# Call (dependency) graph at the level of instruction

Tags: c, profiling

I was wondering. Is there a tool I can use (on a C program) that would generate a call graph at the level of an instruction in a program, taking into consideration the dependency of such instruction on other instructions? Something like a "dependency graph" but at the level of instructions in a program. I took the idea from chapter 27 of the new Cormen book (see for example p. 778), but I won't even try to hack anything if there's a tool already available. (If you want, Chapter 27 is online [here](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/chapters/0262033844chap27.pdf)). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to do dependency analysis? May be you need to do a topological sort. The boost graph library has facilities for graph generation and all sorts of graph algorithms including topological sort. But it is entirely C++.

Comment: You can dump some internal representation of program, e.g. from gcc with options `-fdump-tree-all` and `-fdump-rtl-all`. Some of files will be dumped in SSA (single assignment form), and dependency will be easy to view.

Answer (score 1):

If you're taking inspiration from Figure 27.2 on page 778 of the Cormen/Rivest book, it is not a call graph in the usual sense.
it is a call tree, in which the nodes are execution instances of a function, not the function itself.
It's the call tree of a particular execution of the program, elaborated with information about the variables in each instance, and information about the parallelism.

To get such a complete call tree you're going to have to basically trace the entire execution. With different arguments, you will get a different trace.

It might be easier to help if your overall goal were more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Any optimizing compiler for C should be doing this kind of control-flow analysis.

On the other hand, I have no idea how easy it is to get the graph out of it (in the standalone tool sense)